# Problem displaying the FIGURE number when using dgruyter.sty

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

I'm writing a journal article that uses De Gruyter style. The problem I wasn't able to solve is the following:

When I include a figure, it is displayed correctly, but in the caption the legend "Figure #:", before the text I wrote inside the caption command, does not appear.

The figure can be refered appropiately within the manuscript and the number of the figure is correct (as shown in the picture).

[image]

In the preamble I have

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% (only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```

I'll appreciate any help any one can provide.

In the following link you can have access to the `dgruyter` style.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZQTqSgsWzQmmhneEBO2l9tAqKIbzV46B

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for well more than a decade. Don't use it; use `subfig` instead. Do note that you may need to adjust some of your LaTeX code as the syntax of the `subfig` package isn't identical to that of the `subfigure` package.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It did not work.